# How to access UIImageView globally?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` in my firstView.h file and use it in `firstView.m.` Now I need to access it in my `secondView.m` file as well. How I can access it in both files?
Kindly help me via code.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can declare your uiimageview in another file as extern variable and can include that file in your firstView.m and secondView.m file

Commonfile.h -

```
extern UIImageView *imgView;
```

Commonfile.m

```
UIImageView *imgView;
```

Comment: tnx for quick reply:)
m realy stuck in it from 2 days:(
but still m getting problem.
after "extern UIImageView *imgView" i got two error:
1)Type name does not allow storage class to be specified
2)Epected specifie-qualifier-list before 'extern'

m not able to fix them:( can u plz guide me

Comment: where you are getting these errors? have you created a new file "commonfile.h" and add the above code and import this file in firstview.m and secondview.m file?

Comment: i m getting these errors when i have added code in commonfile.h, after creating file. Actually error are at line "extern UIImageView *imgView;"

Comment: have you imported the UIKit in the commonfile.h ? use this to import - #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

Answer (score 0):

In your firstView.h you can declare the UIImageView as a @property for that class.

[The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) from apple

Comment: tnx for quick reply:)
but i can't understand what you said:(
as m new in iphone development, can u plz give me example for what you said.,

Comment: Do you have an ImaveView in firsView.m and do you want to access it from secondView.m is that right?

Comment: yes i want to set "imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"title1.png"];"
from secondview.m. while UIImageView *imageview is in firstview.h.

Answer (score 0):

you are basically want to use the same image in both the views..right . means that you want to send a imge from one view to another . on button click you go to next view using

`[pushviewcontroller....]`  before this you have to set the image and send along with that and get it in next viewDidload in imageview by setting its property.

Answer (score 0):

Create getter and setters for imageview using @property and @synthesize ,then
create object of FirstView in SecondView file .For that you will need to import FirstView.h.
Now you can access imageView by using this obj as obj.imageview and set its properties as per your requirement.

Comment: thanx for reply.,
i have done same as you said,but still of no use.,
not giving me any error but also not working.,
below m giving the code, plz guide me what i have done wrong:(
i have created object of firstview in secondview after importing firstview file as:

FinalLearnUrduViewController *objectView1;

then i have accessed imageView as:

objectView1.imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"];

but when i run the code specified image is not displayed:(

plz help me out where i am wrong..,
i have tried all the methods suggested by you guyz but....,

Comment: try this:[objectView1.imageview.image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"]];                                             I think it will do.